# How to automate rebuilding docker image and container re-running

Tags: node.js, docker

Usually in NodeJS, if I wish to restart my server on every file change I use `nodemon` to achieve that.

Now, I'm playing with docker for the first time and I was wondering how I can automatically rebuild the image and run it as well on every file change

The script I currently have in my package.json file is this:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "docker build . -t app1 && docker run -p 3000:8080 app1"
  }
```

And to start the container all I do is

```
yarn dev
```

So, on every file change how can I make `yarn dev` run again automatically?

Thanks

Comment: Generally when I am doing development of something that will run in the container. I will just mount my local volume into the container so any file changes I make in my local IDE, will automatically change in the container while its running without rebuilding it. This of course just applies to changes to your scripts or app code. Changes for things like adding new library will need a rebuild of the container. `docker run -it -v $(pwd):/opt/app myimage:latest `

Comment: @ChrisDoyle Thanks for your suggestion. However I attempted your suggestion and code changes didn't reflect after hitting save while the container is still running. Is there something I may be missing out ?

Comment: there is a guide here that does the same thing but with docker-compose, its a common development pattern and has worked in most web frameworks I have have used. https://towardsdev.com/docker-for-local-node-js-development-164844df5cb6. Since you dont show your porject structure, docker file and the command you use to launch docker i cant say for sure

Comment: Since Docker's core model is that images are immutable and containers are isolated from the host filesystem, you wind up with a fairly complicated setup to make it simulate a local live-reloading environment.  Can you put aside Docker for your day-to-day development work and use ordinary Node instead?